# Typescript conditionnal type and branch narrowing

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

With this code

```js
type Identity <T extends string> = T;

type MaybeString = string | undefined;

type StringOrNever = MaybeString extends undefined ? never : Identity<MaybeString>;
```

The compiler complain that undefined is not assignable to type String when using MaybeString as the Identity param.

Wondering if this is related to the distributive property of conditional types, i try that

```
type StringOrNever = [MaybeString] extends [undefined] ? [never] : Identity<MaybeString>;
```

which doesn't work either.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THis is not related to distributivity.

[Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) *act on a generic type*. `MaybeString` in `StringOrNever` is not generic.

`MaybeString extends undefined` does not narrow it to `string`. After this condition, `MaybeString` still `string | undefined`.

In order to make it work, you should parametrize `StringOrNever`.

See this example:

```js
type Identity<T extends string> = T;

type MaybeString = string | undefined;

type StringOrNever<T extends string | undefined> = T extends string ? Identity<T> : never

type Result1 = StringOrNever<'Hello'> // hello
type Result2 = StringOrNever<undefined> // never
type Result3 = StringOrNever<undefined | 'some stirng'> // 'some string'
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3yMyw)

There is an interesting case with `Result3`. In fact, `Result3` is a union of string and never: `"some string" | never`. IN this case, `never` is getting clashed with `string`. SO, how do you want to handle union ? We can turn off distributivity, just **like you did**

```js
type Identity<T extends string> = T;

type MaybeString = string | undefined;

type StringOrNever<T extends string | undefined> = [T] extends [string] ? Identity<T> : never

type Result1 = StringOrNever<'Hello'> // hello
type Result2 = StringOrNever<undefined> // never
type Result3 = StringOrNever<undefined | 'some stirng'> // never
```

Comment: I essentially posted the same thing, but I prefer your answer to mine so I deleted mine and have an upvote instead :)

Comment: @SamuelHulla thank you. After I published my answer I have noticed that my answer is very similar. I can remove mine in favor of yours.  Don't want to be "the plagiator"